# How to make JScrollPane not to scroll after adding rows in the beginning of table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, jscrollpane

I have window that shows log events in table.
For example, user is reading text in some row of table. When new logs come, they are added in the beginning of the table, and the row, the user was reading moves down.  I have a requirement to prevent JScrollPane to scroll when new rows are added at the beginning of the table. I tried diffrent things but nothing helped. Can someone advice me how to implement this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Tricky task :-) The moving out happens because by default the scroll position is *not* adjusted in any way: adding rows above simply keeps the vertical scroll position which then points to a different row as before.

What's needed:

- keep track of the visibleRect/last row *before* the insert
- listen to model changes of type insert
- calculate the new visible rect such that the old last row is scrolled back into the view
- trigger the scroll

It's tricky because we need to listen to model changes. That listener is a neighbour of the modelListener registered internally by the table which updates itself on changes. So we need to be sure to act *after* the internal changes are done and at the same time use information *before* the internal update.

A dirty solution - depending on the usual sequence of swing listener notification which is last-added-first-notified (beware: **DONT** in production code! It will break easily, f.i. when changing the LAF) - is to gather the before-state when notified and adjust the scroll position wrapped in an invokeLater:

```
final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(20, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    model.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
}
final JTable table = new JTable(model);
Action action = new AbstractAction("add row at 0") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.insertRow(0, new Object[] {});
    }
};
JXFrame frame = wrapWithScrollingInFrame(table, "modify scroll");
TableModelListener l = new TableModelListener() {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        if (!TableUtilities.isInsert(e)) return;
        final Rectangle r = table.getVisibleRect();
        final int lastRow = table.rowAtPoint(
                new Point(0, r.y + r.height - 5));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // assuming 
                // a) the insert was exactly 1 row
                // b) was _before_ the old last row in view-coordinates
                Rectangle cell = table.getCellRect(lastRow + 1, 0, true);
                cell.translate(0, -r.height + cell.height);
                cell.height = r.height;
                table.scrollRectToVisible(cell);
            }
        });
    }
};
model.addTableModelListener(l);
```

The appropriate way of getting the before-state cleanly depends on your exact context. You can keep track of the first/last row during the lifetime of the table, updating them in (one or all)

- a ListSelectionListener to the row selectionModel (if the row the user is reading is always selected)
- a ChangeListener to the vertical scrollBar
- a ComponentListener to scrollPane's size changes